# How to do premultiply alpha later in libGDX?

Tags: libgdx

I have straight alpha image files but it needs to become PMA before getting blended. I have a condition that I cannot preprocess the file itself. How can I multiply the color information with alpha on the fly via code before sending it to the `SpriteBatch`? Currently the textures is of the format `TextureRegion`.

I saw that I could draw `PixMap` onto the texture so I can `getTextureData` then get the `PixMap`, change it and then draw it back. But I am not sure if that is the most efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a non-premultiplied alpha image to premultiplied alpha you need to iterate trough each pixel and multiply the colour by the alpha.

```
color.rgb *= color.a
```